# Inline styles not preserved in wordpress table

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table, inline-styles

Our company has developed some very simple table-based clickable html email signatures for clients to use, and we want to showcase them as being clickable on http://scottleroymarketing.com/email-signature but as you can tell...they're not showing up very well.

Setting aside using tables for layout and inline CSS versus a stylesheet (both of which are the easiest way we've found to work within email providers, especially Gmail/GSuite which is what most of our clients use), is there anything within wordpress that would override/mess up the inline styling of the tables? Inline styles trump global CSS from the theme, as far as I'm aware, but there might be exceptions that I don't know about. I'm pretty inexperienced with Wordpress, so I may have been googling the wrong thing (I've looked for "wordpress table styles" and "wordpress inline styles" but all I've found is tutorials for how to apply styles to tables, and fixes for the html/rich text editor not showing on the page). We can screenshot the template as it's supposed to display, and put that on the page, but we'd rather demonstrate how the elements are all clickable versus an image block signature, if possible.

I've previewed the page on Chrome and Firefox, and I figure it will look essentially the same on other browsers since all of the elements I used render about the same on each browser. I'm not sure what version of Wordpress we're using, or how to find it.

Here's the code for the second signature shown on that page, already having been tweaked so that at least the columns are somewhat the correct width:

```
<!-- Begin Signature #2 !-->
<div class="slmsignature1">
<table style="width: 80%; max-width: 700px; min-width: 300px; border: none; border-collapse: collapse; background: url('http://i.imgur.com/SizXUrg.jpg'); background-color: black; color: #fff; font-family:sans-serif;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 200px; font-family:'Gill Sans MT', Tahoma, sans-serif;">
                <img style="width: 100%; max-width: 195px; margin: 0px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/ectryVc.jpg" alt="Scott Le Roy's Head Shot" />
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: bottom; font-family:'Gill Sans MT', Tahoma, sans-serif;">
                <img style="max-width: 160px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/Uns6X52.png" alt="Keller Williams Logo" />
                <p style="font-size: 6pt; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                    Each Keller Williams Office
                    <br />
                    Is Independently Owned And Operated
                </p>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right; font-family:'Gill Sans MT', Tahoma, sans-serif;" colspan="2">
                <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;">
                    Scott Le Roy
                </h1>
                <h2 style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;">
                    CEO/Digital Marketer
                </h2>
                <p style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;">
                    <a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="tel:123-456-7890">
                         C: 123-456-7890
                    </a>
                </p>
                <p style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;">
                    <a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="tel:321-654-0987">
                         O: 321-654-0987
                    </a>
                </p>
                <p style="margin: 5px 5px 0px 0px;">
                    <a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:scott@scottleroymarketing.com">
                         Scott@ScottLeRoyMarketing.com
                    </a>
                </p>
                <p style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;">
                    <a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="http://scottleroymarketing.com">
                         www.ScottLeRoyMarketing.com
                    </a>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 25px; text-decoration:none; font-size:8pt;">
            <td style="text-align: right; font-family:'Gill Sans MT', Tahoma, sans-serif;">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/scottleroymarketing/">
                    <img style="height: 25px; margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/ES2mp6u.png" alt="Facebook Icon" />
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.twitter.com/">
                    <img style="height: 25px; margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/E2iChYF.png" alt="Twitter Icon" />
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/">
                    <img style="height: 25px; margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/dJARSqo.png" alt="Pinterest Icon" />
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                    <img style="height: 25px; margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/Ucw1EDq.png" alt="Linkedin Icon" />
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
                    <img style="height: 25px; margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/lFx5fpA.png" alt="Instagram Icon" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; width 40%; font-family:'Gill Sans MT', Tahoma, sans-serif;">
                123 E. Main St #201
                <span style="color: #b40101;">
                    |
                </span>
                 Anytown, VA 12345
            </td>
            <td>
                Another Placeholder
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Update: I played around some more and it looks like the Wordpress "Text"/code editor is treating line breaks in the code as line breaks in the content as well, and removing `<br />` tags. I've updated the linked page to show that change, but the "Visual" editor is showing it differently than the live page. Ugh.

[Screenshot of the "Visual" editor in Wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcLje.png)

[Screenshot of the actual live page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IN0C.png)

---

#### Solved

Ho-lee hell that was something else. You have to be super duper specific with your markup in wordpress, for each individual `<td>` and everything, or else it will try to apply the default styles to that data, even if you told it not to in the actual table itself. Good thing email services aren't like this...

Anyway, the final verdict is to use a plugin that allows you to disable the "wpautop" plugin for the page so that it doesn't convert line breaks in the code to `<br />` when it renders, then the "Don't Muck My Markup" plugin to have it not convert `<br />` to those same line breaks.

Final code block for that signature that is displaying pretty much properly on http://scottleroymarketing.com/email-signature (second one):

```
<!-- Begin Signature #2 !-->

<div class="slmsignature1">
    <table style="width: 80%; max-width: 700px; min-width: 300px; border: none; border-collapse: collapse; background: url('http://i.imgur.com/SizXUrg.jpg'); background-color: black; color: #fff; font-family:sans-serif;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 200px; font-family:'Gill Sans MT', Tahoma, sans-serif; border:none;">
                    <img style="width: 100%; max-width: 195px; margin: 0px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/ectryVc.jpg" alt="Scott Le Roy's Head Shot" />
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: bottom; font-family:'Gill Sans MT', Tahoma, sans-serif; border:none;">
                    <img style="max-width: 160px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/Uns6X52.png" alt="Keller Williams Logo" />
                    <p style="font-size: 6pt; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                        Each Keller Williams Office
                        <br />
                        Is Independently Owned And Operated
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right; font-family:'Gill Sans MT', Tahoma, sans-serif; border:none;" colspan="2">
                    <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif; margin: -5px 5px 0px 0px;">
                        Scott Le Roy
                    </h1>
                    <h2 style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; margin: -5px 5px 5px 0px;">
                        CEO/Digital Marketer
                    </h2>
                    <p style="margin: -5px 5px 0px 0px;">
                        <a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="tel:123-456-7890">
                             C: 123-456-7890
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <p style="margin: -5px 5px 0px 0px;">
                        <a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="tel:321-654-0987">
                             O: 321-654-0987
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <p style="margin: -5px 5px 0px 0px;">
                        <a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:scott@scottleroymarketing.com">
                             Scott@ScottLeRoyMarketing.com
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <p style="margin: -5px 5px 0px 0px;">
                        <a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;" href="http://scottleroymarketing.com">
                             www.ScottLeRoyMarketing.com
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 25px; width: 200px;text-decoration:none; font-size:8pt;">
                <td style="text-align: right; font-family:'Gill Sans MT', Tahoma, sans-serif; border:none;">
<table style="border:none; border-collapse:collapse; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
<tr>
<td style="padding:0px;border:none;">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/scottleroymarketing/"><img style="height: 25px; margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/ES2mp6u.png" alt="Facebook Icon" /></a>
</td>
<td style="padding:0px;border:none;">
<a href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img style="height: 25px; margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/E2iChYF.png" alt="Twitter Icon" /></a>
</td>
<td style="padding:0px;border:none;">
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/"><img style="height: 25px; margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/dJARSqo.png" alt="Pinterest Icon" /></a>
</td>
<td style="padding:0px;border:none;">
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><img style="height: 25px; margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/Ucw1EDq.png" alt="Linkedin Icon" /></a>
</td>
<td style="padding:0px;border:none;">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img style="height: 25px; margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/lFx5fpA.png" alt="Instagram Icon" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; font-family:'Gill Sans MT', Tahoma, sans-serif; border:none;">
                    123&nbsp;E.&nbsp;Main&nbsp;St&nbsp;#201&nbsp;<span style="color: #b40101;">|</span>&nbsp;Anytown,&nbsp;VA&nbsp;12345
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<!-- End Signature #2 !-->
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using a WP Editor to code your emails.  There's lots and lots of challenges to get an HTML email to render properly across browsers.  Further, you can troubleshoot this a lot more effectively by capturing the HTML being sent in the email either at the time it is sent, or else by using "View Source" in your email client.

Comment: (And - it's pretty much required to use tables and inline CSS to get an HTML email to render properly across the wide range of different email clients!)

Comment: Give this a try to rule out the possbility that WP editor interference is the cause of the problem https://wordpress.org/plugins/dont-muck-my-markup/

Comment: @cale_b Thanks! We're not using the wordpress editor to create the signatures, we're just wanting to showcase the already-created signatures on that page so that people can see how they work.

Comment: @Ihazkode Gracias! I'll see if my boss wants to give that plugin a try.

Comment: @Ihazkode That plugin did help for the editor to not convert `<br />` tags to line breaks, etc, but I think it's still treating a new line in the code as a new line to be rendered :-/ I would hate to have to put the whole code block on a single line to make it work, for 10+ different signatures...

Comment: So it turns out it was the default "wpautop" plugin that automatically converts line breaks in the "Text" editor to `<br />` tags when saving. I searched "wpautop" in the plugins search and found a plugin that adds a checkbox for "disable wpautop" to each page that you can click to turn on. Looks MUCH better now, but still not perfect. I think I may need to take all of those social media icons and put them into a `<ul>` and have them display inline, which isn't an issue outside of wordpress...anyway, will report back. https://i.imgur.com/jtGZue0.png

Comment: I thought I did? @Cœur

Comment: @RobertGreenstreet Oh... I'm not sure to understand why your question has two times a `<!-- Begin Signature #2 !-->` block of code. Maybe I was wrong, but it doesn't seem that "_Ho-lee hell that was something else._" and what follows is an actual question. That's what I mean by moving your solution to an answer. If I misunderstood it, please forgive me. Note as well that asking to look at the issue located at http://scottleroymarketing.com/email-signature seems to be irrelevant now, so all in all you may want to edit your question somehow.

Comment: I think I answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47339321/8948531

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final verdict is to use a plugin (there are several) that allows you to disable the "wpautop" plugin for the page so that it doesn't convert line breaks in the code in the "Text" editor to `<br />` when it renders, then the "Don't Muck My Markup" plugin to have it not convert `<br />` to those same line breaks.

The other thing is that you have to go into each `<td>` element and tell it to not show borders, etc, because Wordpress (evidently) ignores `<style>` elements added to the "Text" editor so you can't apply a style to all `<td>`s, you have to do them each individually :-/

And in the social media icons shown in the bottom left (of the particular signature noted in this post), just adding them to that table cell with the `<a>` and `<img>` tags won't show them inline like it's supposed to, you have to create another `<table>` within that cell, and make each icon its own `<td`> in the same `<tr>` with no padding, also remembering to do "border:none;" on each `<td>`.

Props to @ihazcode for pointing me in the direction of the "Don't Muck My Markup" plugin!